# CSS Positioning on keyDown

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making an airplane game. To shoot missiles I'm using JavaScript functions that create divs with the class of missile and use the position of my airplane to position the missile.

The problem is with my top positioning.

Here is my keyDown function...

```
    document.onkeydown = function(e) {
        (e.keyCode === 37) ? player.left-= 10
        : (e.keyCode === 38) ? player.top-= 10
        : (e.keyCode === 39) ? player.left += 10
        : (e.keyCode === 40) ? player.top += 10
        : (e.keyCode === 32) ? missiles.push({top: player.top - 8, left: player.left + 34})
        : player = player;
        drawMissiles();


        (player.top <= 400) ? player.top = 400
        : player = player;



        drawPlayer();
}
```

This adds an object to an empty missiles array with the properties of "top" and "left."

I'm then using a JavaScript function to add that div to my HTML with the top and bottom properties being used as my CSS style, like so..

```
function drawMissiles() {
            let content = "";
            missiles.map(function(missile) {
                content+= "<div class='missile' style='left:"+missile.left+"px;, top:"+missile.top+"px;'></div>"
                    document.getElementById("missiles").innerHTML = content;
                })
            }
        drawMissiles();
```

My "left" property is working, but my "top" is not. My missiles are ending up at the top of my page.

[image: Pic included.]

Comment: typo in the style property

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a typo. You have a comma after the first semicolon in your style tag.